# a file with 5 columns that one it's column matchs with a columns in another file that each value of it related to more than one concepts in column 2

Tags: text, awk

it is my file 1:

```
A2M 104300
A2M 614036
A2ML1   166760
AADAC   
AARS2   614096
AARS2   615889
```

it is my file2:

```
12  9259200 A   T   A2M
12  8988224 A   G   A2ML1
12  8990939 A   G   A2ML1
3   151545674   C   T   AADAC
6   44272485    C   G   AARS2
```

I want to match column one in file1 to column 5 in file2 in file3 like :

file3:

```
12 9259200 T G A2M 104300
12 9259200 T G A2M  614036
12 8988224 A G A2ML1 166760
12 8990939 A G A2ML1 166760
3 151545674 C T AADAC   -
6 44272485 C G AARS2 614096
6 44272485 C G AARS2 615889
```

I tried this code:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if($5 in a)print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[$5]}' file1.csv file2.csv >file3.csv
```

but I get this result:

```
12 9259200 T G A2M  614036
12 8988224 A G A2ML1 166760
12 8990939 A G A2ML1 166760
3 151545674 C T AADAC   -
6 44272485 C G AARS2 615889
```

Comment: Your test data doesn't match your awk script or your output. `-F ','` makes no sense with space/tab delmited files. And file3 lines 1/2 should surely contain `A T` and not `T G`. Your main problem is that you are using a single variable (`a[$1]`) to try to store potentially multiple items.

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sort, bash and GNU join:

```
join -1 1 -2 5 -e - <(sort file1) <(sort -k5,5 file2) -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,1.2
```

Output:

```
12 9259200 A T A2M 104300
12 9259200 A T A2M 614036
12 8988224 A G A2ML1 166760
12 8990939 A G A2ML1 166760
3 151545674 C T AADAC -
6 44272485 C G AARS2 614096
6 44272485 C G AARS2 615889
```

---

See: `man join`

Comment: thank you for your code. My files are in .csv file. so I use from -t , for "join" and "sort" and removed the -e. so it works.

Comment: but how about awk? how can I do it with awk? I tried very much and but it didn't work.